# How to plot a violinplot from frequency data not using repeat?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data in a frequency table since it is too much data without keeping it like this:

```
value    count    year    status
0        985572   2000    U
1        1857356  2000    U
2        3904079  2000    U
3        6399287  2000    U
4        9321185  2000    U
5        13093158 2000    U
6        16379938 2000    U
7        18409244 2000    U
...      ...      ...     ...
95       3        2000    U
99       3        2000    U
100      5        2000    U
2        1        2000    B
3        9        2000    B
4        13       2000    B
5        19       2000    B
6        23       2000    B
7        80       2000    B
8        69       2000    B
9        82       2000    B
...      ...      ...     ...
49       2        2000    B
50       1        2000    B
53       1        2000    B
```

I need to plot the distribution of these different statuses with a violin plot. However, I cannot seem to figure out how.
The repeat function in Python does not work, as there is too much data and too little computational power.
I want the y-axis to be the `values`, the x-axis to be the `year`, the hue to be `status`, and the distribution of the violin plot to resemble the `count`.
How can I achieve that and not get these uniform violinplots between different statuses?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
sns.violinplot(x='year', y='value', data=test, hue='status', inner='quart', palette = color)
```

[image: img]

Answer (score 2):

You still can used `np.repeat()` by scaling the repitition factors. As the 'U' `status` has much larger counts than the others, scaling needs to be done per `status`. The sums per status and the relative weightings can be calculated via pandas (as shown in the code below).

Instead of `np.repeat`, you could also use a random sample of the data, via weights. Again, due to one `status` group overwhelming the rest, these weights need to be relative to each group.

Here is an example, comparing `sns.kdeplot()` (which supports a `weights=` parameter) to `sns.violinplot()` using a weighted sample of the data. As the automatically choosen bandwidth (for `kdeplot` with weights) seems a bit off here, a bandwidth scaling is applied.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create some test data, a bit similar to the example
# 'status' is changed to `pd.Categorical` for consistent ordering
np.random.seed(20240205)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': np.tile(np.arange(101), 3),
                   'status': pd.Categorical(np.repeat([*'ABC'], 101)),
                   'count': (10 ** np.concatenate([np.random.uniform(0, 7, 101),
                                                   np.random.uniform(0, 4, 101),
                                                   np.random.uniform(0, 2, 101)])).astype(int)})

# calculate a new column with the totals per status
sum_per_status = df.groupby('status')['count'].sum().reset_index().rename(columns={'count': 'status_total'})
df = pd.merge(df, sum_per_status, on='status')

# calculate a new column with the relative weights per status
df['rel_weight'] = df['count'] / df['status_total']

sns.set_style('whitegrid')
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 5]})

sns.kdeplot(df, y='value', weights='count', hue='status', common_norm=False,
            bw_adjust=0.3, ax=ax1)

sns.violinplot(df.sample(10000, weights='rel_weight', replace=True),
               x='status', y='value', hue='status', ax=ax2)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.violinplot with weights]

Here is a more direct comparison between the kde and violinplots. The bandwidths are interpreted a bit different per status group. Dealing with this complication is probably one of the reasons the violinplot doesn't support weights yet.

```py
sns.kdeplot(df, y='value', weights='count', hue='status', common_norm=False,
            bw_adjust=0.35, legend=False)
for index, curve in enumerate(ax.get_lines()[::-1]):
    x = curve.get_xdata()
    curve.set_xdata(x / x.max() * 0.4 + index + 0.1)

sns.violinplot(df.sample(10000, weights='rel_weight', replace=True),
               x='status', y='value', hue='status')
```

[image: comparing violinplot and kdeplots with weights]

PS: According to github issues [2121](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2121) and [2589](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2589) the weights parameter for violin plots has been considered to be implemented in a future overhaul of seaborn's internal structure.